# Grabbing records between Specified Dates when Date is a Timestamp

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a column called helpdate. This column is in timestamp format (yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss). I want to grab only the records from Jan 01, 2021 - Jan 31, 2021, regardless of time. Is there a way to grab these records without having to input the hour/minutes/seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Yes . . . You can just do the comparison:

```
where helpdate >= '2021-01-01' and
      helpdate < '2021-02-01
```